# How to pack string in C++ msgpack?

Tags: c++, msgpack

```
msgpack::object elem;
std::string tempString = "string";
elem["type"] = msgpack::pack(tempString);
```

Above code doesn't work

```
error: no matching function for call to 'pack(std::string&)'
```

How can I pack string into msgpack::object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`msgpack::pack()`](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_cpp_packer) is a free function template in the namespace `msgpack`:

```
template <typename Stream, typename T>
inline void pack(Stream& s, const T& v);
```

The function obviously is stateless and needs a target where to pack the `tempString` to. The target can be any class that has the member funciton `write(const char*, std::size_t);`. For example, use `std::stringstream`:

```
std::string tempString = "string";
std::stringstream messagePacked;
msgpack::pack(messagePacked, tempString);
```

And you might want this:

```
msgpack::object elem;
std::string tempString = "string";
elem["type"] = tempString;
std::stringstream messagePacked;
msgpack::pack(messagePacked, elem);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Would I ask one more question? I'm sorry that I missed some part in question. 
I want to pack string into msgpack::object, and insert it into map.
However, the following code generates error


std::map<std::string, msgpack::object> msgpack;
msgpack["string"] = msgpack::object("string");

`undefined reference to `void msgpack::v1::operator<< <char, 4ul>(msgpack::v2::object&, char const (&) [4ul])'`
How can I solve this?

Comment: Please ask a new question. Comments are not suitable for future SO users that solve similar tasks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77897164/how-to-pack-string-into-msgpackobject-in-c

I'm sorry. I created new question above.